# Data from Cubesat as web API

Tags: artificial-satellite, communication, cubesat

I’m doing some research for possible cubesat mission and I spent days on the internet and in books trying to find a simple answer to my dumb question. I’m completely new in this field so I’m not sure yet where to look for answers.

**I’m trying to find solution on:** How to **share live data from Cubesat on the internet**. How design of such communication should look a like. Let’s say I want to have running **linux OS** on cubesat with some **applications like servers** and etc.

Thank you for your hints and suggestions.

Comment: Remote data is remote data. A good model for what you are doing would be a sensor network based on Raspberry Pi's or Arduino's running on solar power so that they are only "on" part of the time, connected by ZigBee or LoRa or some hands-on wireless system you need to learn (not WiFi, that's too easy). You can then try to read about how people data from that kind of network into a web API in [Arduino Stack Exchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/) or [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/). It's not a perfect match but the share live data aspect is similar.

Comment: I'd recommend you even try to build a cubesat simulator (Raspberry Pi, Solar Cell, Battery, ZigBee over a long distance to a base station) and have some fun with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacecraft usually have different electronic boards which serve different functions. Each is usually an independent "subsystem." For example, one usually has a main "Command and Data Handling" subsystem, called the C&DH (or CDH). This is the main interface to the ground: all the telecommands from the ground go to that board (which usually gets a bit stream directly from the TTX), and all the telemetry (measurement points from different sensors and onboard equipment) is routing through the C&DH and then beamed down to Earth to a ground station.

If you want to display data from your Cubesat online, you'll need first to get the data back on the ground and onto a ground control system (or GCS). There a number of GCS available, and which are either [open source](http://www.kubos.com/majortom/) or [proprietary and made to order](https://www.gmv.com/en/Products/hifly/). Once you've accumulated the data on the ground, you should be able to provide access to a subset of the data to the rest of the world by reading telemetry stored in a database on the ground.

If I may, I would recommend against sharing *all* the data from your spacecraft. A number of telemetry points are used for health monitoring, and as such, they should not be shared with potentially malevolent actors who may try to exploit that in order to take control of your vehicle.

Comment: Thanks, that was an answer that I was looking for.  Major Tom and Kubos OS look like a point of start for me.